# Textarea distinct line alignment using JS

Tags: javascript, textarea

I wonder if it is possible to make **textarea** contain multiple lines with different alignments using JavaScript. 
Something like that:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034191/html-javascript-rich-text-box-ide

Answer (score 0):

Using some sort of wysiwyg editor might get you where you want to go.

[Here are some google results to that fact](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=wysiwyg+editor+javascript&pbx=1&oq=wysiwyg+editor+javascript&aq=f&aqi=g1g-v4&aql=t&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2382l6449l0l9l8l0l0l0l0l244l939l3.4.1l8&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=7c469d2a1253a36a&ion=1&biw=1680&bih=965)

Comment: I don't really want an entire WYSIWYG editor. I want this particular function implemented within regular textarea.

Comment: how would ur users change alignment then??

Comment: Well it's really easy to manually add some button however i actually need this for automatic alignment swap when you type in different languages. I really don't ask a code or something, just point me how can i take particular line inside the textarea and change it's alignment. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I would just customize [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

Example here: http://www.midgard-project.org/documentation/customizing-tinymce-editor/